# Searching on huge amounts of apache access log

Tags: lucene

I want to index and then search a huge amount of apache access logs.

I was thinking about using lucene, I would like to better understand if I need to implement a parser before passing the data to an analyzer.

My goal is to make a lot of composite query.

Do you know how to implement a parser before passing the data to an analyzer?

Comment: Lucene has standard query parsers which handle a reasonably robust syntax for creating queries.  Do you have some particular need that you think will not be handled by the standard [query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/queryparsersyntax.html)?

Comment: You should and read the book "Lucene in Action" to get a good understanding of Lucene.  You can make composite queries using multiple methods in Lucene; for example a BooleanQuery...that however has nothing to do with implementing a parser before passing the data to the analyzer.  Parsing data before passing it into the Analyzer...once again that is a complex topic.  You have analyzers that have stop words, will lowercase all of the data etc as the tokenize the string content.  For example, if u have a large text file, but will only search the header..yes parse out the header.